# Silverlight Slideshow + WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I downloaded this Silverlight project in order to use it on my asp webproject .

http://designwithsilverlight.com/?p=162

The slide show works fine inside its project with WCF methode that returns the img url from my database .

but when I add the XAP file and the html test page to my web project , no img loaded .

any idea ?

Comment: An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI'http://localhost:25573/WebService1.asmx'.This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services.You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve to cross-domain policy

you must create a xml file with this name: clientaccesspolicy.xml, and this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type">
        <domain uri="*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>  
</access-policy>
```

then put this file to root of your web server or your project